# Vue response data storing in html table row

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. In my VUE script below, the console log is showing my data that I expect (26 records to be exact). So I'm trying to take that data that's successfully dumping and adding to `dateEvents` so that I can have each record show up as a row in my HTML table. I obviously know my data is coming back in the response, but why can't I see it in my table?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Available At:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ dateEvents.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data () {
        return {
            dateEvents: [],
            config: {
                defaultView: 'month',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    console.log(event)
                }
            },
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchTasks();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchTasks() {
        axios.get('/dashboard/tasks' )
            .then((response) => {
                // handle success
                console.log(response.data);
                this.dateEvents = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {
        });
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code I am making the assumption that `dateEvents` is an array. In which case you need to add a `v-for` to loop through this array of objects. Try updating your template to the following:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Available At:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="dateEvent in dateEvents">
                    <td>{{ dateEvent.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ah man, that worked perfectly! Thank you. So now I can use if statements around it in the same way

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in the context of your axios `then` function is not your Vue instance.  You need to save off the Vue instance in a variable:

```
var vm = this;
axios.get(...)
    .then( response => vm.dateEvents = response.data );
```

Comment: `this` references the Vue component because it is using ES6 style arrow functions.

Comment: Ah, yes!  Missed that.  Thanks!